# Angular 2 App not loading, and there's not error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-2

My Angular2 App has been working. Not sure what I did, it's now getting stuck at loading, and there's no error message. When I use FireFox, it pops up a Warning: Unresponsive Script

"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://10.60.3.12/polyfills.8ee51304bf305725cfc5.bundle.js:36"

I have been sitting here all day trying to find the problem. I use angular-cli created a new project, and manually copied my source files into the new project folder. It compiles successfully, but the app just won't load.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

**Edit: This is when I run local dev mode. It compiles successfully**

```
Titan:sumo-app eric$ ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200 **
Hash: 840cec4b0f63776f7cf8                                                    - Time: 11228ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 158 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 183 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 10.4 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 4.19 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

I also made some screen shots when I go to localhost with FireFox. The first screen shot is where it gets stuck. My laptop fan starts spinning and getting loud when it gets stuck here. The Second screen shot shows some error 304 from the inspector.

[image]

[image]

**Edit: This code below is causing all the problem. I use this to check if the a user is logged in or if the token is expired. I don't understand how this code is causing the app not loading.**

```
    loggedIn(){

    let expiration = new Date(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expiration')))
    let now = new Date()
    let t = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (t == null || expiration == null) { 
        this.logout()
        return false 
    }
     let u = localStorage.getItem('currentUser')
        if (u != null){
            this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
        }else {
            this.logout()
            return false
        }
    if (now > expiration ){
        this.logout()
        return false
    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: We can't see a script on a 10-dot network.

Comment: If you are running it under production mode it won't fire any error on console have you debug locally under development mode ?

Comment: On local host I did ng serve, I think that's development mode by default. It's the same issue.

Comment: did you try cleaning your app? remove `node_modules` folder and `npm install` then try again.

Comment: Yes, I did clean up my node_modules. I followed the angular-cli update guild here -> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update

Comment: It sounds like you may have introduced an infinite loop. Take a look at the code you added most recently and see if it does anything which may be causing an infinite loop. Add some break points or console.log to help locate the problem.

Comment: I added console.log to each module's OnInit, only the main AppComponent showed the message once. I think this is the correct behavior since I will need to click links to navigate to other components. All the changes I made was spelling related in the html templates. Is there other places I can check?

Comment: I think I fount the problem.  <button class="nav-link" routerLink="/bills" md-menu-item>All Bills</button> the routerLink part should be [routerLink]="['/bills']"